# Factors affecting the size of a shadow

Tags: optics, visible-light, waves

What factors affects the size of a shadow and how would you derive the diameter of a shadow of a circular object on a flat screen?

Comment: It's based on the *distance and orientation* of the light source, whether it becomes an ellipse or a larger circle ;-)

Comment: If the light source isn't pointlike, the shadow doesn't have sharp edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the Circular object I use a cardboard with a circular cavity that will behave same as the object, instead the lighted portion on screen would be shadow in that case `:)`

[image]

$$\tan\theta=\dfrac  r d =\dfrac R{d+D} $$